# Strange behavior when setting height of a table header view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am trying to make my table header equally high as its contents. It seems impossible to do this in storyboard so I tried to programmatically set the height upon loading the view. Yet the table header is much higher than its subviews while the frame size is said to be the same.

I did this in my viewDidLoad function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ongoingOrderTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    tableHeader.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    tableHeader.frame.size.height = 440
    print(tableHeader.frame.size)
    //(560.0, 440.0) 
    print(qrLabel.frame.size)
    //(54.0, 21.0)
    print(qrImage.frame.size)
    //(440.0, 440.0)

}
```

Printed result showed that the settings are correct.

The UI on simulator is as below:[image]

Can somebody explain why did this happened and how to fix that?

Comment: maybe your image is too small? make the UIImageView content mode to aspectFill and see if it changes

Comment: @zp_x nothing happened. According to the output the header view's width should be 560 and height is 440. But it seems its height is bigger than its width. I cannot understand this.

Comment: I think the navigation bar height is about 44, so relatively the header height is around 440. Your image is about 5 navigation bar height, so only around 200. Is the image generated by you or it is a png file?

Comment: If the image is generated, there may be some transparent padding, you can download a png image and try to use it to see whether it displays correctly

Comment: @zp_x it is a png image. The question is even when I set equal height and width for the table header, it's still not square.

Comment: how much width and height do you set? make sure it does not exceed your table view's width

Comment: @zp_x nope. It is exactly my table view's width.

Comment: sorry, you need to post your code otherwise I dont know what is going on. For the original question, I can say the header height is correctly 440.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100679/discussion-between-alvinzoo-and-zp-x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using auto layout, iOS will keep a 600 * 600 screen size until func viewDidLayoutSubviews() is called. Hence you should do your dynamic adjustment of layouts in viewDidLayoutSubviews() rather than viewDidLoad().

I put the print(tableHeader.frame.size) in viewDidLayoutSubviews() as well and the result is (374.0, 501.0). And when I adjust header height in this function it all turned out correct.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the table header view in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.
To debug the issue , add a breakpoint in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and check the header height.

In my experience this happens in case you dont add the tableHeaderView from storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with your navigation bar,

Try switching your top bar to `Opaque Navigation Bar`, Select NavigationController on your storyboard > Simulated Metrics > Top Bar > Opaque Navigation Bar

For example having image view :

[image]

Default/ Transclucent :

[image]

Opaque :
[image]